# Use two different seed to avoid hash conflict?

Tags: hash

Can we use two different seeds to avoid hash conflict? For example:

Given `string_a` and `string_b` and `hash_seed`, we may have a hash conflict.

Now, instead of `hash_seed`, we have `hash_seed_0` and `hash_seed_1`, and we get two hash values for each string. `string_a` will have `hash_a_0` and `hash_a_1`. `string_b` will have `hash_b_0` and `hash_b_1`.

Can we say that it's nearly impossible to have two different strings that will have two same hash value now?

Also, if the hash value is 32bit. Is two hash value equal to have a 64bit hash value? Or two hash value is less likely to conflict than have a 64bit value? or worse?

Comment: Show me a hash function that takes a *hash seed*? But, yes, in general you will have fewer collisions by using 2 hash functions with a total output of 2n bits versus one hash function that outputs n bits. For well designed hash function the probability of any 2 distinct inputs colliding should by 2\*\*(-n) if the hash function has an n bit output.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk for example murmur3 take a seed parameter: https://github.com/PeterScott/murmur3/blob/master/murmur3.c#L71